# OR-Tools - Minimize area covered by every route

Tags: mathematical-optimization, or-tools

I'm using the VRP from OR-Tools to generate routes for hundreds of deliveries in a city. All the packages are picked up in the same location. Currently, I'm minimizing the sum of distances and constraining the number of deliveries per route.

I'd like to add a new cost in the cost function to minimize the area that every route covers. The reason behind is that many routes overlap in the same areas and I would like to have all the deliveries of every route in the smallest area as possible. This could help couriers to deliver only in very specific areas of the city.

My idea of a basic implementation was to create two dimensions to track the min and the max longitude and latitude from the first delivery of every route to the last one (i.e., without considering the depot). Then, I would add a cost based on the difference of the max & min.

However, I don't find a way to store the min & max value of a dimension. As far as I know, the dimension callbacks are stateless and don't depend on previous connections between deliveries and so it can't be done this way.

Any suggestion to accomplish this or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I have wanted to try this out as well, but AFAIK this is not possible with OR-Tools. As you state, the distance callback is stateless in the default API. I have heard of teams that have forked the project and modified it such that the distance callback accepts 3 arguments, but I would imagine that to be rather cumbersome.

My best advice would be to try out Optaplanner as that is more flexible and allows for objectives as minimize bounding box or minimize surface area. I have implemented that in the past with some success.

Though, note that such computations slow the solver down quite a bit.

Comment: Optaplanner and OR-Tools are in a totally different league. OR-Tools contains real solvers (they can find proven optimal solutions), Optaplanner is just a heuristic (it cannot say anything about optimality).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I never mentioned anything about performance or optimization quality. My only comment was that Optaplanner is far more flexible than OR-Tools when it comes to defining objectives in the context of the vehicle routing problem.

While you are right that OR-Tools uses real solvers, the routing library does also rely on heuristics, so I am not sure by what you mean that they are in a different league.

Comment: I will not comment on optaplanner :-) I am sure it is a fine tool. Now, asking to do territorial design while solving the delivery problem seems a bad idea, the area in lat/long seems a very bad proxy to locality in a city (w.r.t. districts). I would solve in 2 phases. One split the city geographically in districts. Then assign 1 or more vehicle to each district. then use the routing library to to the daily delivery plans.